# how to insert data from database in combox

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox, sqlconnection

I'm trying to insert data from my database in a combo box specifically showing all my tables in the combobox here's my connection

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string connetionString = null;
     SqlConnection cnn;
     connetionString = "Data Source=ITWORKSDEV01;Initial Catalog=ITWorksDEV";
     cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
         comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
     }
 }
```

Comment: where is the remaining code?

Comment: why `vb.net` is added in tags?

Comment: ^ its a typo sorry it auto corrected

Comment: After update in the question. Still code is not enough. It is recommended to search about the topic

Comment: YOu're only creating a connection - you're not actually executing any SQL query against the database!

Comment: Well i try to teach him to try it first. Lets see if it works this time :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, which database-type are you using ?

You can look-up the correct connection-code for each database here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Second, don't forget to open the connection:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string connetionString = null;
     connetionString = "Data Source=ITWORKSDEV01;Initial Catalog=ITWorksDEV";
     using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
     {
         cnn.Open();
```

After you opened the connection, create a DataReader and a SQL-Statement:

[SqlDataReader and SqlCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005974/sqldatareader-and-sqlcommand)

```
     }
}
```

Closing/Disposing isn't needed here, [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh598w02.aspx) makes that job for you.

But stackoverflow is not a place where we write you the code, you have to write it by yourself and if you get errors we can help you.

Good luck!

Comment: Note: closing connections is also very important

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes you are right. Closing/Disposing(which includes closing) is important, will add it to the answer.

Comment: Second note :) It's better to use `using` statement to close connection even if exception happens

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy True the second :P Actually I normally use `using`, I think I just wanted to fix the OP's-code and didn't improve it. My bad :)